# Error INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND when access to a virtual host by Microsoft Edge

Tags: centos, virtualhost, vmware, microsoft-edge

I'm new to web developing and now I have some problems trying to access to a virtual host on Microsoft Edge. It's server is CentOS which runs on VMware.

I can access to that virtual host on Chrome, Firefox, IE without any problem, but when I try testing it on Edge, it just shows these errors:

```
Hmmm...can’t reach this page
```

and

```
Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
```

My Edge version is **42.17134.1.0**

Answer (score 0):

Lot of people have this prob nobody asked so I will give you trick that works 100%. You need to rename registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections
```

…to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
```

Detailed guide how to fix [Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND](https://geeksadvice.com/how-to-fix-inet_e_resource_not_found-error-on-wind**ows-10/)